# How to add different edit/update method into rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The controller:

```
def edit  
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to add another methods like this. For updating only 1 column of item and i want to dont show other columns to user.
    I have all neccesary views.

```
def another_edit
end

def another_update
 respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(params[:item].permit(:amount))
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

I thought my routes are wrong. Then tried

```
  resources :items do
    collection do
        get 'add', on: :edit
    end
  end
```

and

```
get 'items/another_edit'
```

Is it possible or not? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add those endpoints in routes as "member" (not collection):

```
resources :items do
   get :another_edit, on: :member
   put :another_update, on: :member
end
```

Then routes will be built with "id" parameter inside.